# Testing method which calls protected method form another class

Tags: testing, reflection, junit, mockito

```
class A {
    protected obj init()
}

class B {
    public void testingThis() {
      //..stuff
      obj = a.init()
      moreStuff(obj)
    }
}
```

I am testing class `B`. I am having trouble doing so because it used class `A`'s method to get an object. How can I solve this?

P.S. can't change visibility, can't put in same package.

Comment: You either have access to a, in this case you mock it. otherwise you should not even bother to know testingThis implementation details

Answer (score 0):

With such constraints, the "simplest" is declaring a class in the testing class or its package that subclasses `A` that is the dependency that you want to mock.
Stub `init()` to return a fixture data and that should be fine.
You can pass it in the constructor of the stub class.

This would give this stub class that you can so use as dependency in your test class :

```
class StubA extends A {

    Foo stubbedFoo;
    public StubA(Foo stubbedFoo){this.stubbedFoo=stubbedFoo}

    @Override
    public Foo init(){
       return stubbedFoo;
   }
}
```

Test sample :

```
class BTest {

    @Test
    public void doThat() {
      StubA a = new StubA(anyFooValue);
      B b = new B(a);
      // action
      b.doThat();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I do B b = new B(a);
There is no constructor for this?

Comment: If you have no constuctor, neither setter to set the dependency, how do you want to set that ?

Answer (score 0):

B is not written correctly to my opinion. The reference to A should have been an injected dependency. Now you have 2 ways to test this: the clean way or the PowerMock way. If you do the clean way, you will refactor B so it has a dependency injected to A and therefor you can control the A class with a mock.

```
class B {
    A myAclass;

    @Inject
    public B(A myAclass) {
        this.myAclass=myAclass;
    }

    public void testingThis() {
      //..stuff
      obj = myAclass.init()
      moreStuff(obj)
    }
}
```

The test now can look something like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Btest {
    @Mock
    A myAmock; 

    @InjectMocks
    B sut; // System-Under-Test

    @Test
    public void testB() {
        X theObject = mock(X.class);
        when(myAmock.init()).thenReturn(theObject);

        // call the method
        sut.testingThis();

        //verify the call being done
        verify(a, times(1)).init();
    }
}
```

If you are unable to change the code of B you can still test it, but you need PowerMock(ito) for this.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTests({A.class, B.class})
public class Btest {
    B sut;

    @Test
    public void testB() {
       A aMock = mock(A.class);
       X thObject = mock(X.class);

       // I can't determine from the code if the init method is static or you use an instance. In case of an instance you must override the constructor:
       PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);
       PowerMockito.whenNew(A.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(aMock);
       when(aMock.init()).thenReturn(theObject);

       // In case of a static method you should mock that method
       when(A.init()).thenReturn(theObject);

       // Now construct B to test it.
       sut = new B();
       sut.testingThis();

       // verify
       verify(aMock, times(1)).init();
    }
}
```